# How i can display sender and receiver message on different side in angular using socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io-1.0

**All things working well but problem is that i want to show sender and receiver message on different side but i don't know how i can implement this i also getting socket ids from server side but i'm not able to create logic how i can differentiate sender and receiver message on my html page please anyone can help me Thanks in advance**

*this is my server side code*

```
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log('a user connected');
 socket.emit('myId', socket.id);

 socket.on('sendMessage', (message) => {
  const sockitID = socket.id;
  console.log(sockitID);
  io.emit('recieveMessage', message); //`${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`
 });

 socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('a user disconnected!');
 });
 });
```

*this is my chatserivce file from agular side*

```
  import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
  import { DefaultEventsMap } from 'socket.io-client/build/typed-events';
  import { MessageModel } from './app.component';

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class ChatService implements OnInit {
    public message$: BehaviorSubject<MessageModel> = new BehaviorSubject({});
    public socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>;
    public socketID: string = ''
    constructor() {
     this.socket =io('http://localhost:3000');
     this.socket.on('myId', (id)=>{
     console.log('from service',id);
    });

    }
   ngOnInit(): void {

   }
   public sendMessage(message:any) {
     this.socket.emit('sendMessage', {message: message, senderId : this.socketID});
     const senderID = this.socket.id;
     console.log('Sender ID = ' ,senderID);
   }

   public getNewMessage = () => {
    this.socket.on('recieveMessage', (message) =>{
    this.message$.next(message);
    const reciverID = this.socket.id;
    console.log('Receiver ID = ', reciverID)
   });

   return this.message$.asObservable();
   };
   }
```

*This is my angular typescript file*

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { ChatService } from './chat.service';

   export interface MessageModel{
   message?: string;
   senderId?:string; 
  }

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
   public socketId: string = '';
   constructor(private chatService: ChatService){}

   newMessage!: string;
   messageList: MessageModel[] = [];

   ngOnInit(){
    this.socketId = this.chatService.socketID;
    console.log('this.socketID',  this.socketId)
    this.chatService.getNewMessage().subscribe((message: MessageModel) => {
    const socketId = message.senderId;
    console.log('Sockit ID = ',socketId);
    this.messageList.push(message);
  
   });
   }
   sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.newMessage);
    this.newMessage = '';
   }
  }
```

*this is my html file for displaying messages*

```
   <div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div *ngIf="message">
      <div   *ngIf="socketId === message.senderId" class="client-chat"> 
        {{message.message}}
      </div>
      <div    *ngIf="socketId !== message.senderId"  class="my-chat"> 
        {{message.message}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*This is my css style to seprate sender message to receiver through styling*

```
 .client-chat{
   width: 60%;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: #4f5d73c7;
   padding: 7px 10px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
   margin: 10px 0px;
 }
 .my-chat{
   width: 60%;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: #77b3d4c7;
   padding: 7px 10px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
   margin: 5px 0px 5px auto;
  }
```

*this is sender side result*
[image]

*this is receiver side result*
[image]

**i am not able to create logic for sepeerating message sender and receiver please anyone can solve my problem Thanks in advance**

Comment: Do the socket IDs print in `console.log` look right?

Comment: yes ids printed but i'm not able to compare sender and receiver id.

Comment: Try adding  `console.log(message)` after `console.log('Receiver ID = ', reciverID)` to see what `senderId` does each message get.

Comment: ok i try this and inform you

Comment: when i log message i giving an object {message: 'asdfjk', senderId: 'zdyw1hKVAeRHWuraAAAG'}   and receiver and sender ids are both same ---> Sender ID =  zdyw1hKVAeRHWuraAAAG
chat.service.ts:36 Receiver ID =  zdyw1hKVAeRHWuraAAAG

Comment: on the receiver window i'm getting different id Receiver ID =  hkgu57xcnbzIFfDxAAAH this is id of receiver and also getting message object

Comment: please can you solve my problem  this is link of my question i'm very thankful to you ---------- >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330719/how-i-can-place-data-intoinput-type-file-in-update-form-when-updating-data-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have never updated `socketID` in `ChatService`

```
this.socket.on('myId', (id)=>{
    console.log('from service',id);
    this.socketID = id;   //missing this line
});
```

Edit:

When you update `socketID` in `ChatService`, the `socketId` in `AppComponent` is not updated, because you only set `socketId` once in `ngOnInit`.

The simplest thing you can do is to completely get rid of the `socketId` field, make `chatService` public and access `chatService.socketID` directly in your HTML template.

```
export class AppComponent {
   //public socketId: string = '';
   constructor(public chatService: ChatService){}

   //...
}
```

---

```
<div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div *ngIf="message">
        <div   *ngIf="chatService.socketID === message.senderId" class="client-chat"> 
            {{message.message}}
        </div>
        <div    *ngIf="chatService.socketID !== message.senderId"  class="my-chat"> 
            {{message.message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also add this line this.socketID = id;  but its  not working please can you help me

Comment: @AmirShahzad see my edited answer

Comment: please can you solve my problem  this is link of my question i'm very thankful to you ---------- >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330719/how-i-can-place-data-intoinput-type-file-in-update-form-when-updating-data-i